# couchbase configuration cluster undefined

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, koa

Using couchbase database, I get this error in `config/db.js`:

```
var cluster = new _couchbase2.default.Cluster(_env2.default.database.cluster);
TypeError: Cannot read property 'cluster' of undefined
```

config/env/development.js:

```
const config = {
    database: {
        cluster: '...',
        password: '',
        bucket: '...'
    }
}

export default config;
```

config/env/index.js:

```
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(`./${env}.js`);

export default config;
```

config/db.js:

```
import config from './env';

const cluster = new couchbase.Cluster(config.database.cluster);
```

Comment: The problem seems to be the `_env2.default.database.cluster`. Have you tried to `console.log(_env2.default.database)` to see if this is defined?

Comment: @SebastianHildebrandt yes config.default.database.cluster work, but why should I add "default"? how can I remove it to config.database.cluster?

Answer (score 0):

Try importing `couchbase` into your file: `config/db.js`

```
import config from './env';
import couchbase from 'couchbase'

const cluster = new couchbase.Cluster(config.database.cluster);
```

Comment: Use config.default.database.cluster work, how can I remove "default"?

Comment: @Alvin use export rather than export default.

Comment: It is a re-export... so need default?

Comment: @Alvin or you can do an import { database } from '.env'